# Speeding up the image loading process

Tags: actionscript-3

How can we speed up the process of loading hundred's of images in as3? it seams to be taking a very long time to load 100's of images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have the ability to change the image quality or sizes, then there isn't a lot you can do to speed up such a large load, as you are limited by connection speed and simultaneous browser connections.

You may be benefitted by using a loading manager, like Greensock's [LoaderMax](http://www.greensock.com/loadermax/). LoaderMax will help make sure you are loading several assets simultaneously - check out the `maxConnections` parameter.

Also, I suggest not loading everything up front with one preloader. Instead, have placeholders with a spinning loader for each image that then gets replaced by the final image once loaded. This will provide a much smoother user experience and create the illusion of the overall load taking less time.

Answer (score 1):

100s of requests can take quite a long time even if the total size of the images isn't prohibitively large. If you know which images you need in advance, you could embed the images in another swf which you load at runtime.

By the way, what is the reason that you need to load 100s of images right away. Is there any reason you can't load them in the background a little more slowly?

Comment: the reason for loading 100's of images is i am trying to create a Photo Mosaic. Currently i have written the code in a way that each image is loaded 1 by 1. What i want to do is accelerate the same process of loading the images 1 by 1.

Comment: Oh! by the way i forgot to mention all the images come from a server which i access using a dynamic xml. i don't have any sort of access to the images to reduce the quality of the images.

Comment: @Sravan0313 Given the extra information you provided, I would take a look at @ilollar's answer. Using a good loading manager should be faster than simply loading the images one by one. I haven't personally used greensock's `LoaderMax`, but it looks like it could be a good option.

Answer (score 1):

A few suggestions:

1. Reduce the filesize of your images (obvious but most important).
2. **Don't run all the requests at once** - queue the images and load them one at a time (most relevant to least relevant).

Comment: I am not running all the requests at once i have queued the loading process already. But the problem is i don't have the access to the images as they are on the server and i access them using a dynamically generated XML.

Comment: Are you able to send me a link to the XML so that I can have a look at some of the images and let you know what I think? It sounds like the images are just way too large. You could create a PHP script that accepts a link to an image and then uses the GD library to compress it before you try and load it in Flash.

Answer (score 1):

There were lots of good advices already. But here a re my 2 cents. One day I had to load about 1000 of really small images. It was taking too long so I used [FZip](http://codeazur.com.br/lab/fzip/) AS3 library. Worked like a charm.

Comment: That's EXACTLY what I was looking for. Hopefully it will work with Adobe AIR for mobile too... Any comments?

Answer (score 0):

The question does not provide a lot of specifics, so here are some general guidelines.

If the images are large JPEGs, you might be able to sacrifice some quality and recompress the images to make them smaller.

If the images are PNGs and represent, e.g., lots of small, individual tiles for a game, you could try combining many of them into a single image and then parsing them out into images on the client side after loading the image over the network.

Answer (score 0):

1. Implement download queue, for example simple loader
   https://github.com/hydrotik/QueueLoader
2. Do not load images that
   currently out of stage (you can load them in background)
3. Use texture packer if you have plenty of small images
4. Optimize pics
   quality (i.e. size, type)
5. Use cache, for instance Local Shared
   Object, so for next time you'll get your pics ultimately fast from
   LSO.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any way to get thumbnails of the images made? If so, you could use the thumbnails while the larger versions load. Load all the thumbnails first (since they'd load really fast), then load the larger versions in prioritized order.

It sounds like you don't have a lot of control over the images, though. If you don't have any control there, there's very little you can do to speed up the process besides using a loading optimizer as others have suggested.